# My SQL + C# Weird Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I'm getting very weird error on the page on every other refresh but NOT every time.

I have a simple page printing out the data as follow:

Backend(aspx.cs)

```
string sql="Select * from content_mgr_multiple where category = '1' limit 0, 1";    
DataView dv = DBAccess.GetListView(sql);
this.ResultList.DataSource = dv;
this.ResultList.DataBind();
```

Frontend(aspx)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultList" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
     <%#  Eval("content") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code work as simple as above but it is showing the following error for every other refresh.
**DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'content'.**

Let's say I refresh the page 6 times. 2nd,4th and 6th time are fine but 1st,3rd and 5th time are showing above error.

I tried to troubleshoot as follow. I put codes to print out the column names in that DataSource.

```
string sql="Select * from content_mgr_multiple where category = '1' limit 0, 1";    
DataView dv = DBAccess.GetListView(sql);
        foreach (DataColumn dr in dv.Table.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(dr.ColumnName + "<BR>");
        }
this.ResultList.DataSource = dv;
this.ResultList.DataBind();
```

On 2nd,4th and 6th time refresh, the column names are printed out in English.

```
id
category
title
titleCh
content
contentCh
```

On 1st,3rd and 5th time refresh, the column names are printed out in Chinese.

```
楤
捡瑥杯特
瑩瑬�
瑩瑬敃�
捯湴敮�
捯湴敮瑃�
```

I have been fighting this for a while and please help. Thanks.

Comment: What provider are you using for db access, the mysql .net connector?

Comment: On the occasions which fail, your backend appears to think that MySQL results are encoded in UTF-16 when they are not (`id` is `0x6964` in ASCII, which is the encoding of 楤 [in big-endian UTF-16](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6964/charset_support.htm)).  I'm no C# expert, but AIUI it encodes all strings in UTF-16?  In which case, you should ensure that MySQL [`character_set_results`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results) is set to `ucs2` (best to do this on opening the connection, or subsequently with `SET NAMES`).

Comment: @Chris. I am using MySql.Data connector. eggyal I executed this command "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';" and it returns 
character_set_client  utf8
character_set_connection  utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_results  utf8
character_set_server  latin1
character_set_system  utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\shar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys very much for your concern. Finally, I found what was causing it. As eggyal pointed out, it made me realize that something was wrong with the database.

I have content_mgr category table which is holding Chinese titles too. In that category table, the Chinese filed was created as "ucs2_general_ci". As soon as I changed it to "utf8_general_ci", the problem is solved.